# Laravel Guzzle post request

Tags: php, laravel, post, guzzle

I have trouble setting my `Guzzle` headers.

```
try {
    $res = $client->post($apiURL,
        [
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'accept' => 'application/json',
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
            ],
            'body' => \GuzzleHttp\json_encode([
                'query' => 'xxxyyy'
            ])
        ]
    );
} catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
    dd($e->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents());
}
```

I get response from server that I need to check my access token, though it passes fine in the Postman when doing the same request. When checking Chrome inspector I am getting

`Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`

I tried setting headers directly in the `new Client()` constructor but I get the same response.

Package used: `use GuzzleHttp\Client;`

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question, what the problem is.

In general, use [the `form_params` option](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#form-params) to pass `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` body and the `json` option to pass `application/json` body. The `Content-Type` header will be set up automatically.

It seems that need to send a form, but you are sending a JSON.